how can childA's state change doesn't render itself, but render childB
I am working on a project, where Parent has two Children - A & B.
childA has a list of buttons, and when the user clicks on one of them, I want to capture the ID of the button. HOWEVER, I don't want childA to be rerendered.
What I want is for childB to receive the ID of the button, and render itself.
I believe using state is why every time a button is clicked, it will rerender ChildA. What's the right way of achieving the desire behavior here?
(for context, I have simplified things to make the problem clear, in reality childA is a map, and childB is a diagram.)
export function Parent() {
  [buttonId, setButtonId] = useState(null);
  return (
    <>
      <ChildA buttonId={buttonId} onClick={(id) => setButtonId(id)} />
      <ChildA inputId={buttonId} />
    </>
  );
}

export function ChildA({ buttonId, onClick }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Button key='1' onClick={() => onClick(1)}>
      <Button key='2' onClick={() => onClick(2)}>
      <Button key='3' onClick={() => onClick(3)}>
      <Button key='4' onClick={() => onClick(4)}>
      <ElementIDoNotWantRerenderedWhenAButtonIsClicked />
    </>
  );
}

export function ChildB({ inputId }) {
  return (
    <>
      <RenderMeElement inputId={inputId}>
    </>
  );
}


Just curious, why did you pass buttonId to ChildA? Are you using/referring it in ChildA which currently your demo didn't showing it?

@YongShun I pass it so when user clicks a button, ChildA can capture the button's Id, and surface it back to Parent, and further pass it to ChildB. Is there a better way of doing this?

Possibly this may help: How can I prevent re-render after state changed in React Hooks?

"I believe using state is why every time a button is clicked, it will rerender ChildA." - Yes, this is correct. When child A triggers a state update in the parent, the parent component and it's entire sub-ReactTree will rerender. "What's the right way of achieving the desire behavior here?" - What you implemented is the correct way to store the state in an ancestor component and pass down the state and callbacks as props to descendent components.

dont pass buttonId to ChildA, just pass the setter

You can use React's React.memo to prevent unnecessary re-renders of ChildA. React.memo is a higher order component, it’s similar to React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes. If your component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result.
Here's how you can apply it to your ChildA component:
export const ChildA = React.memo(({ onClick }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button key='1' onClick={() => onClick(1)} />
      <Button key='2' onClick={() => onClick(2)} />
      <Button key='3' onClick={() => onClick(3)} />
      <Button key='4' onClick={() => onClick(4)} />
      <ElementIDoNotWantRerenderedWhenAButtonIsClicked />
    </>
  );
});

https://react.dev/reference/react/memo
https://react.dev/reference/react/PureComponent
https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit
https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory
